# "Не берись ..." vs "Не вздумай ..."

Tags: словоупотребление

> **Не берись** утверждать, что ты действительно знаешь, какая она.
>
> **Не вздумай** утверждать, что ты действительно знаешь, какая она.

I'm wondering how they are nuanced. Is the former about telling them not to start/set about doing something and the latter more about telling them not to even think about / toy with the possibility of  doing something? In short, dissuading "actions" vs "thoughts"?

Also, I notice that one is perfective and the other imperfective.

Comment: correct, the 1st is 'don't try to claim' while the 2nd is 'don't even entertain a thought of claiming', **не вздумай** has a synonymous imperfective counterpart **даже не думай**

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I often use "Не вздумай" myself but have never heard "Не берись" in imperative before. Is "Не берись" less emphatic and more polite or formal?

Comment: **не вздумай** is stricter, more categorical, more demanding, **не берись** is closer to a recommendation in intensity

Comment: In colloquial English, one of the idiomatic phrasings for this is "But **don't go** claiming that ...". Do you think it corresponds more to "Не вздумай" than "Не берись"?

Comment: to me the English one sounds disdainful (am i wrong about that?) unlike these Russian imperatives which are neutral, therefore not sure i can match it up with any of them, i guess the most straightforward translation would be **don't attempt to** and **don't think of doing**

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка True. "Don't go + gerund" can have a disdainful flavour as well as a patronising tone -- mother to son, for instance. I was under the impression that "Не вздумай" shares this tone. I see now.

Comment: yeah patronizing and haughty it can be, so not necessarily neutral, it often comes as **не вздумай мне** to underscore this connotation

Answer (score 4):

For starters, the last one is much more colloquial, along the lines of "don't you dare...".

The first one is "don't claim", "don't bear the responsibility", compare to `Взялся за гуж, не говори, что не дюж` [proverb](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/17896145).

The last one is "don't you think", "don't you dare".

So, the first one is about "I do not recommend you to bear the responsibility of [doing something]", while the last one is "I advise you not to [do something]" or "if you [do something], you'd deal with me". Compare to `Сейчас морозы! Не вздумай выйти на улицу без шапки!`.

Comment: Agree. Не берись - like a warning you'll likely to fail. Не вздумай - like a stronger warning maybe smth bad can happen if you do it, etc.